# Getting the difference of two DateTime instances in milliseconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

What would be a proper fool-proof way of doing so? I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
        DateTime a = ...
        DateTime b = ...
        var ms = a.Subtract(b).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: it should be var ms = b.Subtract(a).TotalMilliseconds; Otherwise correct! thanks! i was using TimeSpan class and it was not giving the correct value.

Comment: Well this actually does use the TimeSpan class; the result of DateTime.Subtract() is a TimeSpan.

Answer (score 7):

```
(datetime2 - datetime1).TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking this should work.  Since you asked for foolproof, I'm assuming you don't know which of the two is the later date :)

```
Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalMilliseconds)
```

Comment: Technically this gets the distance, not the difference. Though +1 because I feel that this is most likely what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction would be my choice...

```
DateTime earlier = DateTime.Now;
// ...
DateTime later = DateTime.Now;
double result = (later - earlier).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Int64 GetDifferencesBetweenTwoDate(DateTime newDate, DateTime oldDate, string type)
    {
        var span = newDate - oldDate;
        switch (type)
        {
            case "tt": return (int)span.Ticks;
            case "ms": return (int)span.TotalMilliseconds;
            case "ss": return (int)span.TotalSeconds;
            case "mm": return (int)span.TotalMinutes;
            case "hh": return (int)span.TotalHours;
            case "dd": return (int)span.TotalDays;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```